# How to take backup of Single table in SSIS Package

Tags: ssis

I want to take backup of **single table** on same server but in different backup database, backup table name should like "*tablename_currentdate+7*". Also I want to **check if backup table is present** in backup database or not. If yes I want to drop that table.

Please suggest how to perform this task in **SSIS package.**

Comment: SSIS doesn't do backups. You can't backup a single table, you can back up a file group. You are talking about *replication* or  simply copying data

Comment: Why don't you use SQL Server's availability features instead of copying data like that? Or you can use partitioning for older data. You can move a partition eg from a current to a history table in milliseconds with [parition switching](http://blog.pragmaticworks.com/table-partitioning-in-sql-server-partition-switching) as that's just a metadata operation. What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

1. Establish a connection to both databases
2. I would suggest creating a table in the backup database and always use it. something like tablename_BU
3. Exec SQL Object to TRUNCATE the table
4. put in a data flow
5. connect to source and select * from TABLE
6. Put in a destination and map.

VIOLA